# Regex to remove apostrophe

Tags: regex

I have input text that contains a ' like in this text "Frank's Reel Movie Reviews"

how do I get rid of the '

I have tried

```
.replace (/\'/ig, '');
.replace ('\'', '');
```

But it seem like the ' does now want to be deleted...

I am thinking that the ' maybe encoded utf-8 or something

Any ideas

Comment: Are you sure that it's a ' and not the curved ones that MS Word uses?

Comment: Please tell me you're not doing this so you can compose an SQL command with the text.

Comment: hehehehe oh yes that is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: so I have changed the isert like (#text#, #text#, #text#) and run a command to change the ' to something else and then the # back to '

Comment: #),(#Casino Development#, #major million 5 reel#, #english#, #August#, #http://www.google.com#, #http://www.casinolowdown.com/online-progressive-slot-games/one-million-reels-bc-progressive-slot.html#, #One Million Reels BC progressive slot machine Sloto'Cash : Casino#, #NA#, #report_website#), Here is a more complete example

Comment: Sloto'Cash <<<< It just sticks there and does not want to delete...

Comment: Wait, you're serious? You're trying to build an SQL command? *STOP!* Go research how to correctly do this: by using parameterized queries!

Comment: If you're using this for a sql command please, please use a parameterized sql query. Otherwise you will open yourself to a huge Sql Injection attack.

Comment: Thanks Peter and PB I am using it in a closed enviroment on a local pc...

Comment: That's not the point, Gerald. There are better, much better ways to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex `[^\w ]` will match anything that is not alphanumeric or space.

You could use this to ensure all apostrophes/quotes/etc get removed, even if done with Unicode - though there is not enough information in the question to know if this is acceptable.

Comment: I need some other special characters in the string like # , // etc... it is just the bugging ' that I need to kill

Comment: Then you can add the special characters to the class - e.g. `[^\w #/]` - but more importantly ***give more details in the question on what you're trying to do and what language this is!***

Comment: (/[^\w #\/,\?]/ig,"") hahahha - Thought it would be answered in minutes - THANKS A MILLION PETER - just learned something new!!!

Comment: No problem. I'd still recommend a proper parameterized query though - as well as safer it could be better performance.

Comment: &#39;  <<< I have now accessed that the apostrophy were actually encoded into &#39; - and use this (/\&#39;/ig,"");

Answer (score 6):

*This is late reply but summarizing the answer with quality answer with code addressing different ways of doing it.*

You do not need to use escape sequence when detecting apostrophe. The correct regular expression would be

```
/'+/g
```

This will remove *all* apostrophes from the regular expression, if if there are occurrences like ' or '', or ''' and so on.

Here is the code snippet which removes only one instance of apostrophe from a string.

JavasScript

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
name = name.replace(/'/,'')
alert('The result string ' + name);
```

PHP

```
$subject ="Mik's sub";
$resplace = "";
$search ="'";
$new_str =  str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
echo "New Subject : $new_str";
```

Unicode with JavaScript

```
var regex = /\u0027/;
name = name.replace(regex,'')
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're working with Java, have you tried .replaceAll("'", "")? Works for me.

Comment: I have tried it Brabster that is why I am thinking it is some sort of encoded ' cause I just don't get to kill it

Comment: The examples you gave had escaped the quote, which is why I suggested this. I guess I might start converting the string to hex and comparing it with some character code tables. Tricky without more context about where the string comes from

Answer (score 1):

The ' should not need to be escaped. Try leaving it naked, without the backslash.

Comment: var stripped31 = htstring31.replace("'","");  <<< I have tried it but the bugger sticks

Comment: this indeed works in Javascript. Code --> `input = input.replace(/'/,'')`

Comment: Also works in PHP `$new_str =  str_replace("'", $replace, $subject);`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have letters and spaces in your result, you could always match any character that *isn't* one of those, such as...

```
.replace (/[^a-zA-Z ]+/ig, '');
```

You could of course also add any other characters you desired to permit to the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Apostrophe is not a meta character.you should not escape it.

Comment: Allen it is either I escape the apostophre or I have no database, sometimes we need to do stuff to make what we want to work, even if it is not conventional...

Comment: Hi allen, sorry I now only see what you meant with it is not a meta character should not need to be escaped! - Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

If you want something very selective to remove (or replace by anything like a space) apostrophes but not the symbol ' for feet imperial unit, use:

```scala
val apostropheRegex = """(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[a-zA-Z])"""
"john's carpet is 5' x 8'".replaceAll(apostropheRegex, "XXX") // johnXXXs carpet is 5' x 8'
```

It means "Replace all symbol ' that are between two letters".