# Regex to remove special character

Tags: c#, regex

I created a regex that removes the special characters like(<>'&) and make first letter of each word capital and stuff underscore(_) between two words. For example,
Input : `"V_DV3501_Value can't be empty"`
Output: `"V_DV3501_Value_Cant_Be_Empty"`

The regex that I have created is producing output as,

Output: `"V_DV3501_Value_Can't_Be_Empty"`

The concern is apostrophe(') character is not replaced from the string. I am ok if you cansuggest any other pattern than I have below in code for solving this problem.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string createString = "";
        string input = "";

        var pattern = @"(?:[^a-zA-Z_]*)((?<output>[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[\s+&<>\',\/=-]*|$)*";

        var subject = "V_DV3501_Value can't be empty";

        subject = subject.ToString().Replace("&", "and");

        var regex = new Regex(pattern);

        var match = regex.Match(subject);
        Console.WriteLine("pattern: {0} {1} Length: {2}", pattern, match.Success, match.Length);

        foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups["output"].Captures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    {0} @ {1} length {2}", capture.Value, capture.Index, capture.Length);

            input = capture.Value + "_";

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                input = input.First().ToString().ToUpper() + input.Substring(1);
            }

            createString = createString + input;

        }

        createString = createString.Remove(createString.Length - 2);
        Console.WriteLine("Final: " + createString);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to remove apostrophe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219915/regex-to-remove-apostrophe)

Comment: Please check if [this is working as expected](http://ideone.com/AFaeEy).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot for your quick response.

Comment: Great I could help. This is definitely not a duplicate of [Regex to remove apostrophe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219915/regex-to-remove-apostrophe). I posted the answer with explanation, please consider accepting if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
var str = "V_DV3501_Value can't be empty";
var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"[\W-[']](\p{L})|'", m =>
      m.Groups[1].Success ? string.Format("_{0}", m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper()) : "");
Console.WriteLine(res);
// => V_DV3501_Value_Cant_Be_Empty
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/AFaeEy)

The idea here is to use `[\W-[']](\p{L})|'` regex that matches either any non-word character except the `'` (with `[\W-[']]`, to replace with a `_` later) followed with a letter (with `(\p{L})`) and capture the letter so that later we could check if the group participated in the match (and if yes, turn it uppercase), or just match `'` to replace it with nothing.