# JavaScript Regex: apostrophe TRUE for PC version, FALSE for mobile

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm designing a quiz with user data input, which matches to the array of possible answers. The website is responsive and I want to give mobile users more slack with answers involving apostrophes, so they don't have to switch over their keybords to special symbols layout i.e.:

PC version:
"that guy's snowboard" - ok;
"that guys snowboard" - fail

Mobile version:
"that guy's snowboard" - ok;
"that guys snowboard" -  ok

The code I've made so far:

```
var snowboardarr = ["that guy's snowboard"];
var snowboard = document.getElementById("snowboard");
var flag = false;
for (var i = 0; i < snowboardarr.length; i++)
{ if (snowboard.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-=*@#№$%&^()"/]/g, '').toLowerCase() ==
snowboardarr[i].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-=*@#№$%&^()"/]/g, '').toLowerCase()){flag = true;}
else if
(screen.width <= 650 && snowboard.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-=*@#№$%&^()"/]/g, '').toLowerCase() ==
snowboardarr[i].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-=*@#№$%&^()"/]/g, '').toLowerCase()){flag = true;} 
         }
if (flag) {snowboard.style.backgroundColor = "#83C183";}
else {snowboard.style.backgroundColor = "#E06969";}
```

I need, somehow, to exclude apostrophe ' from PC version's regEx and bind it to specific place, where it's meant to be:

that guy's snowboard - ok;
that guys snowboard' - fail

Any help with this, guys, please?

Comment: Might want to take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219915/regex-to-remove-apostrophe

Answer (score 0):

You may use `RegExp` constructor to customize accepted character range based on screen size.

Try this:

```
var snowboardarr = ["that guy's snowboard"];
var snowboard = document.getElementById("snowboard");
var flag = false;
var char_range = "a-zA-Z0-9-=*@#№$%&^()\"";
var char_range_desktop = char_range + "'";
var regex_desktop = new RegExp("[^" + char_range_desktop + "]", "g");
var regex_mobile = new RegExp("[^" + char_range + "]", "g");

for (var i = 0; i < snowboardarr.length; i++) {
  if (screen.width > 650) {
      flag = (is_answer_matching(regex_desktop)) ? true : false;
    }
  else {
      flag = (is_answer_matching(regex_mobile)) ? true : false;
  }
}
function is_answer_matching(re_device) {
  return snowboard.value.replace(re_device, '').toLowerCase() == snowboardarr[i].replace(re_device, '').toLowerCase();
}

snowboard.style.backgroundColor = (flag) ? "#83C183" : "#E06969";
```